# Bootstrap div border taking spaces

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

Hi!

I'm using **bootstrap 4** and making my own project. After some time I found a **problem** which I can't fix. I have placed an image into a div section and made the div to be 200px of height & width and overflow will be hidden. Then I made the height of the image 100% of the div and gave a background color(bg-light) and border(5px solid black) to the div. **But the background color is seen 1px left, top and right of the div and the image is placed after the 1 px left, right and top**.

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="profile-image-container">
    <img class="profile-image" src="image.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.profile-image-container{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.profile-image{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: your problem is not clear. what you want to do ?
and add more code border which define your outer div

Comment: Did you see the image?

Comment: Yes! of course.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question properly.. please tell us what you want as a output.
Find the code below, whatever I understand so far

```
<img class="profile-image" src="img.jpg" width=100% />
```

Comment: If you are not sure, ask a question in the comments. the answer part is not necessarily for ranting or venting frustration.

Comment: I don't want to see the white background, please see the image first.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code from the original question, with a placeholder image.

Unlike the image posted to the question, there is no white border between the enclosing div and the image.

[image]

The may be some additional CSS that was not included in the question to account for the white border between the div and the image.

```css
.profile-image-container{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.profile-image{
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:#e0e0e0; padding:0.5rem">
<div class="profile-image-container">
    <img class="profile-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/210x200" />
</div>
</body>
```